# while loop inside a trigger to loop through all the columns of table in sql

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, triggers

I have a trigger like below on user table to insert into the audit table with which column was updated and previous value:

```
ALTER TRIGGER [dbo].[trgAfterUpdate] ON [dbo].[tbl_User]
AFTER UPDATE
AS


    declare @fieldname varchar(128) ;
    declare @OldValue varchar(255);
    declare @CreateUser varchar(100) ;
    declare @User_Key int;

    select @CreateUser =i.user_name from deleted i; 
    SELECT @User_Key = i.user_key from inserted i;  

    if update(user_name)
      begin
          select @OldValue=j.user_name from deleted j;  
          set @fieldname = 'user_name';

            insert into tbl_Audit(user_key, field_name, previuos_Value, user_name)
            values(@User_Key ,@fieldname,@OldValue, @CreateUser);

      end
```

But my questions is I have like 100 fields on my table. I can't write 100 if conditions. And i need a suggestion how to use while loop in it, and how is it going to effect the performance.

Thanks

Comment: Why not just use XML for this?

Comment: Can you elaborate please? I am not sure how to insert into AUdit table using XML

Comment: Convert the entire row to XML using `FOR XML` and just store and XML column in your audit table.

Comment: But i want only updated column with previous data of that column...Some time out of 100 there may be 2 0r 3 fields updated. i need only those three fields

Comment: there's no pretty way to do what you want.  You will have to write a loop to compare every column in `inserted` and `deleted` and then output the deltas.  I'm telling you that what you want to do is problematic and you should consider an alternate method.

Comment: Do you think using xml is the only alternate way?

Comment: I don't think it's the ONLY way but it's probably the fastest way, for writes at least.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Try this one -

```
ALTER TRIGGER [dbo].[trgAfterUpdate] 

    ON [dbo].[tbl_User]
    AFTER UPDATE

AS BEGIN

    SET NOCOUNT ON
    SET XACT_ABORT ON

    DECLARE @DocumentUID UNIQUEIDENTIFIER

    DECLARE cur CURSOR FORWARD_ONLY READ_ONLY LOCAL FOR
        SELECT DocumentUID, ...
        FROM INSERTED

    OPEN cur

    FETCH NEXT FROM cur INTO @DocumentUID, ...

    WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0 BEGIN

        DECLARE 
              @BeforeChange XML 
            , @AfterChange XML

        SELECT @BeforeChange = (
            SELECT *
            FROM DELETED
            WHERE [DocumentUID] = @DocumentUID
            FOR XML RAW, ROOT
        )
        , @AfterChange = (
            SELECT *
            FROM INSERTED
            WHERE [DocumentUID] = @DocumentUID
            FOR XML RAW, ROOT
        )

        INSERT INTO dbo.LogUser (DocumentUID, BeforeChange, AfterChange)
        SELECT @DocumentUID, @BeforeChange, @AfterChange

        -- your business logic 

        FETCH NEXT FROM cur INTO @DocumentUID, ...

    END

    CLOSE cur
    DEALLOCATE cur

END
```

Comment: I don't need the complete row.I just need the field which has been modified and its previous value.Thanks for your reply though...

Comment: You only need find the difference between `@BeforeChange` and `@AfterChange` values.

Comment: Can you tell me the best way to compare the these two xml variables

Comment: Please see this topic - http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/sqlexpress/thread/3b0600a1-e13e-44e0-b602-36bd3a04714f.

Comment: these two xmls are totally different from normal xml file

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/31721/discussion-between-user1882705-and-devart)

Answer (score -1):

Try using query similar to this one – it will generate If statements for all columns of a given table.

Note:  This is not fully tested and probably needs more adjustments but you see the idea behind it.

```
select 'if update(' + C.name + ')
  begin
      select @OldValue=j.' + C.name + ' from deleted j;  
      set @fieldname = ''' + C.name + ''';

        insert into tbl_Audit(user_key, field_name, previuos_Value, user_name)
        values(@User_Key ,@fieldname,@OldValue, @CreateUser);
  end'
from sys.all_columns C
inner join sys.tables T on C.object_id = T.object_id
where T.name = 'table_name' and T.schema_id = SCHEMA_ID('schema_name')
```

If wouldn’t go with while loop because it can probably cause perf issues…

Comment: so in your query i just need to replace table_name with my table name which is tbl_User right?

Comment: Can you tell me how to debug this trigger? It is not working on my table.