# Handling Subquery returned more than 1 value in SQL Server AFTER UPDATE TRIGGER

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, triggers

I have the following original trigger that has been working fine for me: http://pastebin.com/raw.php?i=mbsrYvJq

I recently found out that this does't work when the table (this trigger is placed on) recieves bulk updates. I get the following error:

> Msg 512, Level 16, State 1, Procedure IC_ProductUpdate, Line 7
>   Subquery returned more than 1 value. This is not permitted when the
>   subquery follows =, !=, <, <= , >, >= or when the subquery is used as
>   an expression. The statement has been terminated.

So I did some digging around and came across this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/17059565/2332336

So, I updated my trigger to use cursor and it now looks like this:

```
ALTER TRIGGER [dbo].[IC_ProductUpdate] 
ON [dbo].[StockItem]
AFTER UPDATE
AS
BEGIN
    SET NOCOUNT ON
    SET XACT_ABORT ON

    DECLARE @StockItemID INT

    DECLARE cur CURSOR FORWARD_ONLY READ_ONLY LOCAL FOR
        SELECT StockItemID
        FROM INSERTED

    OPEN cur

    FETCH NEXT FROM cur INTO @StockItemID

    WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0 BEGIN

        -- Proceed If This Product Is Syncable
        IF (dbo.IC_CanSyncProduct(@StockItemID) = 1)
        BEGIN

            -- Check If Product Was Synced
            IF ((SELECT COUNT(*) FROM IC_ProductCreateQueue WITH (NOLOCK) WHERE StockItemID = @StockItemID) > 0)
            BEGIN

                -- Check If Any Important Columns Was Updated
                IF (UPDATE(Weight) OR UPDATE(SpareNumber1))
                BEGIN

                    -- Check If There Is A [ProductUpdate] Queue Entry Already Exist For This Product
                    IF ((SELECT COUNT(*) FROM IC_ProductUpdateQueue WITH (NOLOCK) WHERE StockItemID = @StockItemID) > 0)
                    BEGIN

                        -- Reset [ProductUpdate] Queue Entry
                        UPDATE IC_ProductUpdateQueue SET Synced = 0
                        WHERE StockItemID = @StockItemID

                    END
                    ELSE
                    BEGIN

                        -- Insert [ProductUpdate] Queue Entry
                        INSERT INTO IC_ProductUpdateQueue (StockItemID, Synced) VALUES
                        (@StockItemID, 0)

                    END

                END

            END
            ELSE
            BEGIN

                -- Insert [ProductCreate] Queue Entry
                INSERT INTO IC_ProductCreateQueue (StockItemID, Synced) VALUES
                (@StockItemID, 0);

                -- Insert [ProductUpdate] Queue Entry
                INSERT INTO IC_ProductUpdateQueue (StockItemID, Synced) VALUES
                (@StockItemID, 0);

            END

        END

        FETCH NEXT FROM cur INTO @StockItemID

    END

    CLOSE cur
    DEALLOCATE cur

END
```

When I try to update the trigger (F5), it doesn't seem to work and gives me this error:

> Msg 207, Level 16, State 1, Procedure IC_ProductUpdate, Line 12
>   Invalid column name 'StockItemID'.

Any idea why this might be? Is there a better way to update my trigger to handle multiple rows being updated at same time?

Comment: **Oh my gosh.....** Please ***do not*** use cursors inside a trigger! That's about the ***worst*** you can do for performance! Rewrite this to a **set-based** operation - this will otherwise kill all your db performance. ..... a trigger should always be very small, fast, lean - and cursors are anything but that.....

Comment: Hi marc_s, thanks for the tip. Can you provide an example or link to guide on how to do a *set-based* operation?

Comment: You're doing **way too much** processing in this trigger. A trigger executes in the context of the statement that caused it to fire, and should be very lean, fast, nimble. Do **not** put extensive processing in a trigger! Instead: in the trigger, only make a note of what needs to be done into a "command" table; then create a separate process (a T-SQL scheduled job, for instance) that checks that "command" table e.g. once every hour, and if need be, does the heavy processing. This way, your trigger becomes (a) much simpler to write, and (b) much less of a burden on your database system

Answer (score 0):

I see your original trigger from the first link in the question, the problem is here:

```
DECLARE @StockItemID INT = (SELECT ItemID FROM INSERTED);
```

You should handle multiple affected row, you could do it with `join`s and not declared any cursor, you don't need above declaration, for example:

```
IF ((SELECT COUNT(*)
      FROM IC_ProductCreateQueue 
     WHERE StockItemID = @StockItemID) > 0)
```

could be wrote as:

```
IF ((SELECT COUNT(*)
      FROM IC_ProductCreateQueue ic 
     join inserted on ic.StockItemID = i.StockItemID) > 0)
```

and

```
UPDATE IC_ProductUpdateQueue SET Synced = 0
                    WHERE StockItemID = @StockItemID
```

could be wrote as:

```
UPDATE IC_ProductUpdateQueue 
SET Synced = 0
WHERE StockItemID in (select StokItemID from inserted)
```

and

```
INSERT INTO IC_ProductUpdateQueue (StockItemID, Synced) VALUES
                    (@StockItemID, 0)
```

could be wrote as:

```
INSERT INTO IC_ProductUpdateQueue (StockItemID, Synced) 
select StockItemID,0 from inserted
```

hope these be helpful.

Comment: Will this work with checking if a particular column is updated I do on this line `IF (UPDATE(Weight) OR UPDATE(SpareNumber1))` ?

Comment: Just compare the `INSERTED` and `DELETED` instead of using `IF UPDATE(`

Answer (score 0):

In my trigger, I need be able to call the `dbo.IC_CanSyncProduct()` function against the row's PK before proceeding as well as only do work when a certain column is updated (i.e. `IF (UPDATE(Weight) OR UPDATE(SpareNumber1))` etc...)

So, I have gone for a temporarily table solution and implemented a pseudo foreach method like this:

```
ALTER TRIGGER [dbo].[IC_ProductUpdate] ON [dbo].[StockItem]
AFTER UPDATE
AS
BEGIN

    SELECT RowNum = ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY ItemID) , ItemID
    INTO #ProductUpdates
    FROM INSERTED;

    DECLARE @MaxRownum INT;
    SET @MaxRownum = (SELECT MAX(RowNum) FROM #ProductUpdates);

    DECLARE @Iter INT;
    SET @Iter = (SELECT MIN(RowNum) FROM #ProductUpdates);

    WHILE @Iter <= @MaxRownum
    BEGIN

        -- Get Product Id
        DECLARE @StockItemID INT = (SELECT ItemID FROM #ProductUpdates WHERE RowNum = @Iter);

        -- Proceed If This Product Is Sync-able
        IF (dbo.IC_CanSyncProduct(@StockItemID) = 1)
        BEGIN

            -- Check If Product Was Synced
            IF ((SELECT COUNT(*) FROM IC_ProductCreateQueue WITH (NOLOCK) WHERE StockItemID = @StockItemID) > 0)
            BEGIN

                -- Check If Any Important Columns Was Updated
                IF (UPDATE(Weight) OR UPDATE(SpareNumber1))
                BEGIN

                    -- Check If There Is A [ProductUpdate] Queue Entry Already Exist For This Product
                    IF ((SELECT COUNT(*) FROM IC_ProductUpdateQueue WITH (NOLOCK) WHERE StockItemID = @StockItemID) > 0)
                    BEGIN

                        -- Reset [ProductUpdate] Queue Entry
                        UPDATE IC_ProductUpdateQueue SET Synced = 0
                        WHERE StockItemID = @StockItemID

                    END
                    ELSE
                    BEGIN

                        -- Insert [ProductUpdate] Queue Entry
                        INSERT INTO IC_ProductUpdateQueue (StockItemID, Synced) VALUES
                        (@StockItemID, 0)

                    END

                END

            END
            ELSE
            BEGIN

                -- Insert [ProductCreate] Queue Entry
                INSERT INTO IC_ProductCreateQueue (StockItemID, Synced) VALUES
                (@StockItemID, 0);

                -- Insert [ProductUpdate] Queue Entry
                INSERT INTO IC_ProductUpdateQueue (StockItemID, Synced) VALUES
                (@StockItemID, 0);

            END

        END

        SET @Iter = @Iter + 1;

    END

    DROP TABLE #ProductUpdates;

END
```

I tested the code like this:

> UPDATE StockItem set Code = Code where ItemID in (965638, 965650,
>   965662, 965674, 965686)

and now it works (no more `Subquery returned more than 1 value` error):

```
(5 row(s) affected)
(1 row(s) affected)
(1 row(s) affected)
(1 row(s) affected)
(1 row(s) affected)
(1 row(s) affected)
(1 row(s) affected)
(1 row(s) affected)
(1 row(s) affected)
(1 row(s) affected)
(1 row(s) affected)
(5 row(s) affected)
```

The only problem with this method is that; checking if specific columns were updated is not working.

Is this a bad idea? wrong approach?