# Sync Primary Key in Parent and Child Table

Tags: t-sql

I need to keep 3 columns in 2 different tables synchronized.

MS SQL Server 2008

```
create table a(
     id int IDENTITY(1,1),
     name1 nvarchar(255),
     name2 nvarchar(255),
     date1 date default null,
     date2 date default null,
     ...
     CONSTRAINT pk primary key (id),
     CONSTRAINT uniqueNames UNIQUE (name1,name2))
```

I'm looking to create another table that will duplicate the first 3 columns in my second table, and keep them up to date (insert, delete, update). I was looking at triggers, but the consensus seems to be that if I insert or update multiple rows at once, this will not execute correctly. Any idea's on how to accomplish this?

Comment: Which database are you using?

Comment: Why? just creating a view `create view table_y as (select id,name1, name2 from table_x);` will give you exactly the same information, with less redundancy.

Comment: I need to add additional date columns in the second table for a different task

Comment: ... which will still be functionally dependent on table_x.id. Makes no sense to me.

Comment: Maybe, I'm making this a little more complex than it has to be. My table (a) has about 140 columns with various nvarchar and dates. I was looking to create two smaller tables. Would it be better to just use one large table? or use 2 and only transfer the id column?

Comment: @wildplasser That's just what I was looking for! Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ideally you would normalise the data by moving the duplicated fields in to another table and referencing them via a foreign key.

However triggers could also be used to solve this problem. take a look here : [How to write trigger for multiple row update?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9493779/how-to-write-trigger-for-multiple-row-update)

Comment: Thanks Gary, this is definitely the answer to my question. As wildplasser and you pointed out, it looks like I was asking the wrong question.